# Why my jquery is not working for a span tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to display some message in span. but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            /****************************First Name validation******************************/
        $("#txtFirstName").bind("focusout",function(){
                if($(this).val()=="" || $(this).val()=="First Name")
                    {
                    $(this).siblings("span[id*='error']").text("First Name Required");
                    $(this).val("First Name");
                    }   
            });

        $("#txtFirstName").bind("focusin",function(){
                if($(this).val()=="First Name")
                    {
                    $(this).siblings("span[id*='error']").show("slow").text("");
                    $(this).val("");                    
                    }   
            }); /********************End First Name validation*****************************/
    });
```

Here is my html code for above code

```
 <td><input id="txtFirstName" type="text" value="First Name" runat="server"/><span class="error"></span></td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `class` instead of `id`:

```
$(this).siblings("span[class*='error']").text("First Name Required");
```

But if the full class name is always `error` you can just use `span.error` or even better, if the `span` comes always after the `input`, use `.next()`:

```
$(this).next().text("First Name Required");
```

Comment: The downvote is really unnecessary. Yes, I was partly wrong before but at the very beginning, there was indeed a `]` missing. And I corrected my answer. And those who downvote without comment are .... well there is nothing to say about this anymore.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Hehe thank you... I upvoted you as well, maybe I should comment that ;) Btw the video you linked to in one of your comments was really interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
$(this).siblings("span.error").text("First Name Required");
```

Answer (score 3):

[Ivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251555/ivo-sabev) has it right, you need `span.error` for a selector in this case.  As a side note though, you can simplify the code a bit overall with chaining and making use of the [`.focusin()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [`.focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) shortcuts:

```
$(function(){
  $("#txtFirstName").focusin(function(){
      if($(this).val()=="First Name")
          $(this).val("").siblings("span.error").hide();
  }).focusout(function(){
      if($(this).val()=="" || $(this).val()=="First Name")
         $(this).val("First Name").siblings("span.error")
                .text("First Name Required").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the span selector try: span.error

```
$(this).siblings("span.error").text("First Name Required");
```